# Check if a string is at the end of the file

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const file = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('input.log'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

file.on('line', (line) => {
  if (line.includes('warning')) {
    fs.appendFile('output.log', '\r\n\r\n', err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  } else if (line.includes('error')) {
    console.log(line)
    fs.appendFile('output.log', line + "\r\n", err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The code works but I need to avoid putting the two newlines when "warning" is on the last line of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this. This code won't save the last warning line at all:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const file = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('input.log'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

let lastLine = '';
file.on('line', (line) => {
  if (lastLine) {
    fs.appendFile('output.log', lastLine, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }

  if (line.includes('warning')) {
    console.log(line);
    lastLine = '\r\n\r\n';
  } else if (line.includes('error')) {
    console.log(line);
    lastLine = line + '\r\n';
  }
  else {
    lastLine = null;
  }
});

// only write last line if it was error
file.on('close', () => {
  if (!lastLine || lastLine === '\r\n\r\n') {
    return;
  }
  
  fs.appendFile('output.log', lastLine, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to write line by line the contents of "input.log" into "output.log" and I want to remove the "\r\n\r\n" at the end of the file.

Comment: @chillin 
and this code should do that.
So it will write all the lines, except at the end if the line was warning it won't write anything

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Comment: @chillin Fixed it. Can you try now?

Comment: lastLine is not defined

Comment: @chillin Well, I added one check just in case you can try again one last time. It is working for me.

Comment: it doesn't save nothing in the file

Comment: @chillin does your input file contain "warning" and/or "error" ? Please make sure your input and output files are correct. I am testing locally and code works fine

Comment: now it works but it duplicates some lines

Comment: @chillin Ok, I added the else statement to fix that

Comment: everything works, is there a way to delete also the newline inserted from the second to last line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246407/discussion-between-chillin-and-irakli-tchedia).